# If image has shape( 28,28,3,1) how do I convert it to shape (28,28,3)?

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, opencv

If image has shape `(28, 28, 3, 1)` how do I convert it to shape `(28, 28, 3)`?

I guess in my case the last `1` of the shape is the batch size.

Comment: Look at NumPy's [`squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) method.

Comment: can you show me how to use it?

Comment: `img = np.squeeze(img)`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comment `np.squeeze` is the most principled way to do it. Adding a few details.

```py
import numpy as np

image = np.ones(shape=(28, 28, 3, 1))
print(image.shape)  # (28, 28, 3, 1)

image = np.squeeze(image, axis=-1)
print(image.shape)  # (28, 28, 3)
```

*I also strongly suggest to always specify in explicit the axis that you want to squeeze with `axis` parameter*, to avoid removing by mistake other singleton axes. Indeed, `np.squeeze` removes by default all single-dimension entries. This can be problematic if you load e.g. a grayscale image.

```py
gray = np.ones(shape=(28, 28, 1, 1))
print(gray.shape)  # (28, 28, 1, 1)

gray = np.squeeze(gray)
print(gray.shape)  # (28, 28) may not be what you want
```

---

Edit: Let me add also a word of notice on the use of `np.reshape` in this case.

It is true that `np.reshape` will work. However, it's worth noting that it will work even in all cases when it shouldn't, which might lead to nasty bugs. Example:

```py
# Due to a bug, you have an image whose shape is different from
#  the one you expect, which is (28, 28, 3, 1)
image = np.ones(shape=(56, 14, 3, 1))

# Reshape will still work, since (56 * 13 * 3) == (28 * 28 * 3)
#  so you won't notice - yet the reshaped image will be nonsense!
reshaped = np.reshape(image, (28, 28, 3))
print(reshaped.shape)  # (28, 28, 3)
```

---

You can also simply use indexing for the same purpose, according to your personal preference.

```py
image = np.ones(shape=(28, 28, 3, 1))
image = image[..., 0]  # same as: image[:, :, :, 0]
print(image.shape)  # (28, 28, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy's reshape function.

```
import numpy as np
reshaped = np.reshape(image,shape=(28,28,3))
```